# Add an API in Kong

Tags: spring-boot, kong

New with REST and API Gateway. I have installed Kong with Cassandra on a dev machine and I'm trying to add my API (spring-boot application) but reading the documentation I'm struggling to make it work. My API:

```
http://ff-nginxdev-01:9003/fund-information-services/first-information/fund/{fundId}
```

when I run

```
http http://ff-nginxdev-01:9003/fund-information-services/first-information/fund/630

    HTTP/1.1 200
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 14:47:30 GMT
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    X-Application-Context: application:9003
    
    {
        "assetSplit": {
            "allocationHistories": [
                {
                    "key": {
                        "asset": {
                            "description": "Other Far East",
                            "id": 18
                        },
                        "assetSplit": "09",
                        "effectiveDate": 1430348400000
                    },
    ......
    ......
```

Everything look fine and I'm able to retrieve the JSON message. Adding the API in Kong:

```
http POST http://ff-nginxdev-01:8001/apis/ name=fund-information upstream_url=http://ff-nginxdev-01:9003/ request_path=/fund-information-services


    HTTP/1.1 201 Created
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 14:39:45 GMT
    Server: kong/0.9.4
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    
    {
        "created_at": 1480084785000,
        "id": "fdcc76d7-e2a2-4816-8f27-d506fdd32c0a",
        "name": "fund-information",
        "preserve_host": false,
        "request_path": "/fund-information-services",
        "strip_request_path": false,
        "upstream_url": "http://ff-nginxdev-01:9003/"
    }
```

Testing Kong API gateway:

```
http http://ff-nginxdev-01:8000/fund-information-services/first-information/fund/630

HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 14:44:33 GMT
Server: kong/0.9.4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

An invalid response was received from the upstream server
```

I know I'm missing something but it is not clear to me.

Comment: Nginx is probably unable to resolve `ff-nginxdev-01`. Make sure to properly configure Nginx to use a resolver which is able to resolve it (you can do so via Kong's config file) and ideally use FQDNs.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Dynamic SSL plugin will binds a specific SSL certificate to the request_host in API.
You just define `request_path` in your API and that means SSL plugin does not apply when you use `request_path`.

You can read more to understand why it is like that in: [this issue](https://github.com/Mashape/kong/issues/1803#issuecomment-259272152)

To make your request works, I think you should read about how to proxy an API in: [Proxy Reference](https://getkong.org/docs/0.9.x/proxy/)

Here is my solution for your problem:

## Method 1: Change "strip_request_path" to true

```
"strip_request_path": true
```

This method assume you didn't specify request_host first

## Method 2: Using request_host instead

```
"request_host" : "your_api"
```

Then in your request header, you should add this request_host:

Example request:

```
curl -i -X POST --url http://ff-nginxdev-01:8000/fund-information-services/first-information/fund/630 --header 'Host: your_api'
```

and it will works

Answer (score 0):

you missed the api name known by kong "fund-information", so if you do this

http POST http://ff-nginxdev-01:8001/apis/ name=fund-information upstream_url=http://ff-nginxdev-01:9003 request_path=/fund-information-services

your test url is
http http://ff-nginxdev-01:8000/fund-information/first-information/fund/630